# Upload data from Azure Automation Account Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-automation, azure-data-explorer

I have some code which pulls out a Kusto query from Azure Monitor and I need to upload the data to a blob storage account for long term retention.

I can pull out the data and display it in the azure automation screen when I run through the test pane, but it doesn't upload to blob.

I think the error is here

```
    $SearchResult 

    $StorageAccountName = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "AccessKey"
    $StorageAccountKey = Get-AutomationVariable -Name "StorageAccName"

    foreach ($sr in $SearchResult){        
$ctx = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName `
         -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey    
$ContainerName = "Data"    
New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Context $ctx -Permission Blob

$BlobName = "$sr"
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -Blob $BlobName `
        -Context $ctx
```

The full script is below

https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/RyLJZVKW

Basically it authenticates using some stored variables and then runs a query which returns the results below (up to that part works), but then I'd like to upload the data to Blob.

The output example can be found at:

https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/fEF6NsnK

If there's a better way of getting a kusto query stored straight to blob storage I'd be happy to consider that .. thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` call seems to be missing the `-File` parameter. You probably get a message complaining about this in the job Error stream.

Assuming that you want to send the data stored in the `$sr` variable, something like this should work (not tested):

```
$tempFile = New-TemporaryFile
$sr | Out-File -FilePath $tempFile.FullName
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent ... -File $tempFile.FullName
Remove-Item $tempFile
```

Comment: Hi thanks, I wasn’t sure how to capture each file and send to azure as it passed through the loop, how do I send each file to blob storage?

Comment: Brilliant I’ll give it a go :)

Comment: Hi I'm getting this error `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $ContainerName -File $temp ...` I have amended the code to https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/4TXEqsKE  I think $seachResult is an array, maybe?